# How to get current URL in Angular 2.0+

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I know this has been asked many times and I have tried to look for a solution.

My current URL is: `http://localhost:4200/configuration`

Below is one of the many online found solutions I am trying to implement.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app';
  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() { 
    console.log("On Init");
    console.log(this.router.url);
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.url);
    //this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

On reload of page I get below output.

```
On Init 
\
```

I am just getting empty url. I am very curious to know what I am missing.

Comment: what do you expect to output?

Comment: shouldn't I get /configuration ??

Comment: show your routes confguratoin

Comment: do you only want to get '`/configuration` ?

Comment: @Faisal yes if possible.

Comment: see update in my answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it using `location.href`. Another option is to use `DOCUMENT` from `'@angular/platform-browser'`:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any){
    console.log(location.pathname);
    console.log(location.href);
    console.log(this.document.location.href);
}
```

If you only want to get "`/configuration`" from your url, then use  `location.pathname`.

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isnjbh?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: This is from Javascript. Is there no way to do this right in angular?

Comment: this is angular. Have you seen the demo ?

Comment: its kind of a hack. i did it in a batter way but have refer once in office tomorrow

Comment: Why add the overhead of Angular if you can do something simply in JavaScript.  That's a silly constraint to this Answer.

Comment: @Graham ,  The OP has asked for an angular specific solution \o/

Comment: Very much aware of that, but Angular is a JavaScript framework therefore a JavaScript solution is also an Angular solution by proxy.

Answer (score 2):

This will give "/configuration"

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

....

constructor(
    private router: Router,
....

ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser) {
      this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .subscribe(() => {
          console.log(this.router.routerState.snapshot.url);
        })
    }
  }
```

or

```
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.router.url)
  }
```

Comment: Works for me, by removing the "filter" line: if (isPlatformBrowser) {
      this.router.events.subscribe(() => {
        console.log(this.router.routerState.snapshot.url);
      });
    }

Comment: @MiguelLara, just this.router.url gives the same result :)

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the property correctly.  However, you're accessing it before it's set.  See:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8phmvc

If you check the browser log you can see which part of each component's lifecycle has it set.

But long story short, instead of ngOnInit try ngAfterViewChecked or look for another way to subscribe to the current location using router.